# Using hex-value from fileGetString in other array

Tags: arrays, capl

I have a what I think easy question, but unfortunately can't find the solution on my own.

I have an array with hex data in .txt file (e.g. 0x01 0x02 [...]) and want to use this data for another function. 
Purpose is, to use some parts of the array (in this example array-number 100) in addition to static values that doesn't change and send a request to an ECU.

when I read the data with fileGetString from file and print it to console, it would be fine (like 0x01 0x02 and so on).

When I try to use it for function you see below, it don't take the right hex value (e.g. StringLongWrite[100] = 0xFF) but in trace data just uses "30".

So the sended Request would be 11 12 13 30 instead of 11 12 13 FF, for the below example.

Is there an easy way to fix this? 
(originally I got the data I want to write in format "01 02 03 ... FF ..." in .txt file and already converted this to the "0x01 0x02 0x03 ... 0xFF ... " data, just in case the first datatype is easier to use...)

Many thanks and regards Robert

```
case  1:    /* write memory */
            if(something);

      glbHandleWrite = openFileRead ("test.txt",0);

      if (glbHandleWrite != 0 && fileGetString(StringLongWrite, elcount(StringLongWrite), glbHandleWrite) != 0)
      {
      SendReq[0] = 0x11;
      SendReq[1] = 0x12;
      SendReq[2] = 0x13;
      SendReq[3] = StringLongWrite[100];
      SendRequest(ServicePhys, 4);
      setTimer( TimeOutTimer, TimeOutLong);
      write ("data %s", StringLongWrite);
      break; 
      }

      else write("Data file cannot be opened ");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0x30` is the ASCII code for the character `'0'`.

You need to convert the string `"0x30"` to a number, eg. using `strtol()`:

```
on start
{
  message 0x123 msg;
  char StringLongWrite[32] = "0x01 0x02 0x03";
  long data[2];
  dword pos = 0;

  pos = strtol(StringLongWrite, pos, data[0]);
  pos = strtol(StringLongWrite, pos, data[1]);
  pos = strtol(StringLongWrite, pos, data[2]);

  write("0x%02x,0x%02x,0x%02x", data[0], data[1], data[2]);

  msg.dlc = 8;
  msg.byte(0) = 0x42;
  msg.byte(1) = data[0];
  msg.byte(2) = data[1];
  msg.byte(3) = data[2];

  output(msg);
}
```

Comment: Thank you sergej for your feedback, I will try to understand and use your solution. appreciate & best regards Robert

Comment: Your solution is working! If I would have had more reputation, I would have of course upvoted ;) Thank you very much !

Comment: Hello sergej, thanks for your hint, now I can upvote :p I have one more question: If I want to define element [X] out of Stringlongwrite to be converted with the strtol-command (e.g. 30, 31,...), do I have to define a whole "data"-array until the last used value?

Comment: pos = strtol(StringLongWrite, pos, data[30]);
     pos = strtol(StringLongWrite, pos, data[31]);
        
      rqBuf[0] = 0x3D; 
    ...      rqBuf[6] = 0x0A;
      rqBuf[7] = data[30];
      rqBuf[8] = data[31]; but it only took the elements from Stringlongwrite from [0, 1, ... and so on] and not [30, 31, and so on]

Comment: `dword pos = 4 * 30;` ?

Comment: If you use data[2], the definition should be: long data[3];